# IOS: animation for a .png

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, png

I want to animate a png in different versions; then I have three versions of this png... a darker version, a medium darker version and a clare version. In my animation I want to do this type of animation

dark -> medium dark -> clare -> medium dark -> dark -> medium dark ->.....

is it possible?

Comment: yes. it's possible. At first, you can write complex algorithm and change image brightness as you need. But the most easiest way is to animate 3 images in repeat mode:)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

sounds like you want to animate uiimageview

```
// create the view that will execute our animation
UIImageView* campFireView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

// load all the frames of our animation
campFireView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:    
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire01.gif"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire02.gif"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire03.gif"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire04.gif"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire05.gif"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire06.gif"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire07.gif"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire08.gif"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire09.gif"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire10.gif"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire11.gif"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire12.gif"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire13.gif"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire14.gif"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire15.gif"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire16.gif"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire17.gif"], nil];

// all frames will execute in 1.75 seconds
campFireView.animationDuration = 1.75;
// repeat the annimation forever
campFireView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
// start animating
[campFireView startAnimating];
// add the animation view to the main window 
[self.view addSubview:campFireView];
```

http://appsamuck.com/day2.html

Comment: The above is bad advice, you should not use the UIImageView.animationImages API. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112698/how-to-do-animations-using-images-efficiently-in-ios/8113027#8113027 for an approach that will not crash when run on the device.